# OkHTTP how to replace team_number from url POST

Tags: android, okhttp

I have url like this.

http://host/parallel/team/:team_number.json

and it has post params. 
like team_number, team_name.

How to make a post request such that i replace team_number to team number with a value.

Does :team_number need to be handled differently ?

So far i have done

```
RequestBody formBody = new FormBody.Builder()
            .addEncoded(TEAM_NUMBER,tracking_number)
            .add(TRACK_NAME, name)
            .build();

    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url(SEND_TRACKING_DATA)
            .post(formBody)
            .build();

    Response response = CoreApplication.okHttpClient.newCall(request).execute();
    return response.body().string();
```

Comment: what have you done so far ?

Comment: and what is the problem now? What is not working?

Comment: no its not working.. in postman its working but not using ohhttp

Comment: **how exactly** it is not working? is it crashing? or what?

Comment: you said team_name is parameter and you've set TRACK_NAME so make sure TRACK_NAME have value team_name

Comment: can you tell how add required parameter to url using okhttp

Comment: it has.. i am getting response also.. but its not reading track_name ...

Comment: if you're getting response then what's the issue ?

Comment: what means when we add : in url ?